# How to enable Poly line editable option in Google Android Native Map?

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3

Am trying to implement the editable poly lines in the google native.

[image]

As per google map api [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) no option there for android.

any other solutions or help for this problem ?

this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351744/drag-polyline-onmarkerdrag-android-google-maps-v2) only giving drag able marker but am looking for that adjustable dots you can find on below picture.

Comment: What do you mean by Editable Poly lines? Can you please brief

Comment: check this link https://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-area-calculator-tool.htm

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko this answer only giving drag able marker but am looking for that adjustable dots you can find on above picture.

Comment: You can use dot image (or any custom image) as [marker image](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14811579/6950238).

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko check this link you will see the difference https://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-area-calculator-tool.htm

Comment: Some points (e.g. even) can have icon like marker "bubble" with white dot at bottom of it, some (e.g. odd) - as only white dots. There is totally same solution for your and that questions. Just try to implement it: format markers as you need ant put it on polyline points, then in `onMarkerDrag()` redraw red border polyline and in `onMarkerDragEnd()` redraw polygone fill. Do you want, that someone else do that for you?